# How to connect to GCP SQL Server using connection name?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I have a question regarding how to connect to GCP SQL Server using connection name?

Currently, as I understand, GCP supports connecting to SQL Server using private IP, public IP, and using connection name (after creating a tunnel). I tried all the three. As I have been instructed not to use IP address to connect, the other option is to use connection name, but I don't want to create a tunnel and use 127.0.0.1 to connect.

Is there a possibility to connect to SQL Server instance using connection name and/or hostname without creating a tunnel?

1. We were previously working with AWS and are not planning to switch to GCP. AWS allowed connecting using a connection name and a host name. Is there such a functionality available is GCP?
2. What is the host name for GCP SQL Server instance?
3. Does the public/private IP of SQL instance change with replications, deployment to different zones, etc?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: _What is the host name for GCP SQL Server instance?_ I don't know about GCP, but AWS and Azure tell you what the host name is. Doesn't GCP? Can you find the screen shown a third of the way down this page? https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-sql-server-on-gcp-692e4ac44cad it appears to tell you the hostname

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Do you mean the instance connection name at https://miro.medium.com/max/334/1*e4qwLlbiRuJo-k66y1imsQ.png ? That will not work.

Comment: Yep and above that is a picture showing "instance connection name" which is a name, not an IP. I've never used GCP before, I'm just googling

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That one doesn't work without a proxy and tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect programmatically with the cloud SQL connectors using the connection name, e.g. [Python example for SQL Server here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-connectors). Otherwise all current methods need the public IP or create a tunnel, neither of which you're not supposed to use.

1. GCP databases use dynamically assigned regional public IP addresses, unfortunately there is no globally available host like the Azure `<instance>.database.windows.net`. Private IPs are also dynamic.
2. GCP databases have instance names but not hostnames.
3. Yes, both private and public IPs are dynamically assigned on instance creation. Regional failovers will keep the same public IP though (just tested to make sure).

The only other solution I can think of is to maintain a DNS zone with the instance public IP addresses since they should never change once created. This might add cost and maintenance overheads though.

Comment: Re: "GCP databases use dynamically assigned regional public IP addresses"
At create time?  Of does the IP change if the instance is shutdown and restarted?
For public and/or private IPs?  (sorry this is all run together stackoverflow comments don't support basic formatting)